# Windows Phone 10 on Nokia Lumia 920

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-920

Is it at all possible to install any version of Windows 10 on the Nokia Lumia 920?

I can't believe this great phone is becoming useless, so I am willing to deploy preview versions or whatever else is available,

Specs from insider app,

```
App version - 1.4.0.1
OS version - 8.10.14219.341
Branch - WPB_CXE_R1
OEM - NOKIA
Model - RM-821_eu_italy_310
FW version - 3051.50009.1451.1009
```

From Upgrade Advisor app,

[image]

Comment: You could install before the release of the anniversary update. I did in my daughter's Lumia 920. Now it does not receive more updates.

Comment: I wish. I've been trying but from what I could find, we can no longer get any release. unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last few months have been quite frustrating.

First I was told my Lumia 920 wasn't getting Windows 10, then it got absolutely shut down from [insider as well](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/4sezso/psa_if_you_want_windows_10_mobile_on_your_lumia/).

Well, this weekend I've decided to spend some time on it, and along with some interesting links from @Indrek's answer, I finally got it.

[image]
[image]

If - like me - you are looking for a short answer, then the answer is **yes**, you can have Windows Phone 10 on your Lumia 920. Needless to say, this answer comes with a...

### **disclaimer**

- This is not supported by Microsoft, and for a reason. CPU and Memory capabilities of these phones weren't enough to pass the quality standards so don't expect the phone to be as fluid, as fast, or even functioning properly as in natively supported phones
- Some of the things we have to do may brick your phone
- You'll need a bunch of applications and configurations so if you're expecting a turn-key solution, then this is NOT for you
- Be prepared for hard resets, which means all information gone. So make backups if you have to.

---

### what you'll need

- Grab the latest [Windows Phone Internals](http://www.wpinternals.net/) version
- Grab registry tool [CustomPFD_0600.xap](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-phone-8/development/xap-custompfd-registry-editor-tweaks-t2981057)
- [WDRT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12379/windows-10-mobile-device-recovery-tool-faq) (Windows Device Recovery Tool)
- Visual Studio + Windows Phone 8.0/8.1 SDK (or [standalone WP SDK](http://nokiaviews.com/unlock-windows-phone-bootloader-and-enable-mass-storage.html))
- [Engineering SLB3](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3735246&d=1462016551)
- [HEX Loaders](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3735247&stc=1&d=1462016555)
- Your phone's ROM (I got mine by running WDRT and installing the version available there, then grab it from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Packages\Products\RM-821)

**how to soft reset**

(hold) vol down + power

**how to hard reset**

1. Turn your Lumia 920 off.
2. Press Volume DOWN and keep pressing it while you connect the charger until you see an exclamation mark!.
3. Press - in this order - Volume UP - Volume DOWN - POWER - VOLUME DOWN.
4. Your phone will reset and reboot. Pls be patient during the reset process.

---

### Procedure to deploy Windows 10

1. Hard reset. phone should go to a lower version such as 8.10.12393.890. since you'll be needing your ROM exported, you may want to use WDRT for this and then grab the rom from the Packages folder
2. When your phone boots up, make sure to pick "Custom" settings and disable all automatic updates of apps and system (it's important that you don't update the <strike>settings</strike> extras+info app)
3. Use the ootb phone system update to get the latest available update. minimum required being 8.10.14219.341. I got 8.10.14234.375

We are now basically following the steps from WPInternals (direct copy from "Getting Started"):

- Flash a Windows Phone 8.1 FFU - **done**
- Run Windows Update until you have at least version 8.10.14219.341 of the OS - **done**
- Unlock the bootloader using an Engineering SBL3 (only possible on compatible phones)

  **To do this, click "Unlock bootloader" and input the 3 parameters: ROM, LOADER folder and SBL3 file. [click here for detailed procedure](http://nokiaviews.com/unlock-windows-phone-bootloader-and-enable-mass-storage.html)**
  [image]
- Run the Windows Insider tool and update to Windows 10 Mobile, possibly needs to run Windows Update a couple of times for the latest build (I had to chose **Insider Fast**, otherwise it would not trigger the update)
- <strike>Enable Root Access directly on the phone</strike>

Now for the tricky part. For the phones that were not allowed Windows 10 after the anniversary update, you will not be able to get preview builds anymore, so you'll have to pretend that your phone is actually the 950XL.

For this you'll have to:

- register your phone to be developer unlocked
- deploy and run CustomPFD_0600.xap
- go to HKLM > System > Platform > DeviceTargetingInfo

What I did was create a table with both old and new values as a backup, then actually write/set the new values for each entry, then reboot the phone.

---

**Key**/OldValue/NewValue

**PhoneModelName**                             Lumia 920             Lumia 950 XL

**PhoneHardwareVariant**                 RM-821                RM-1085

**PhoneManufacturer**                          NOKIA                 MicrosoftMDG

**PhoneManufacturerModelName**  RM-821_eu_italy_310   RM-1085_11302

---

With the new registry settings, you should now be able to use the insider app to request a new build. If everything works as expected you will get a prompt to reboot and short after the update will pop. It make take a few attempts and take a while, but it should work. Make sure root access is disabled at this point (if for some reason you have enabled it) or it could block the update.

---

### troubleshooting

**Cannot register developer phone device**

--> make sure it has internet access

**Device Portal greyed out in Windows 10 PC**

--> make sure "Developer features" is setup to "developer mode"

**Error deploying xap 0x8974006**

--> make sure phone is not in lock screen

**Errors deploying xap 0x81030110 / 0x81030120 / 0x810310B**

--> this issue is typically an unsupported Capability referenced in the MAppManifest.xml file. to work around this, you'll have to make sure that your phone has an unlocked bootloader. if you still get this, try also enabling root access

**Not getting updates (8007000d)**

--> make sure phone is not rooted

---

### best links

http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/windows-10-mobile-apps-and-games/app-dht-upgrade-advisor-redstone-lumias-t3434774

http://nokiaviews.com/unlock-windows-phone-bootloader-and-enable-mass-storage.html

---

### final result

[image][image]

Comment: this is not working anymore! insider app => server error You have to use iutool => http://jayd.ml/windowsphone/2018/06/29/windows-10-lumia-435-tmobile.html best regards wopro

Answer (score 2):

As [Kolappan Nathan said in his answer](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/14204/1401), many older Lumia phones are not officially supported for the Windows 10 Mobile upgrade anymore. However, there are unofficial ways in which they can still be upgraded. I will link to a few resources I've found, but I won't summarise the steps here, because a) I can't personally vouch that they will work and not brick your phone, and b) they may well stop working for future W10M versions. I strongly recommend you read all available information and weigh the benefits and drawbacks before making the leap. Caveats abound!

- Steve Litchfield at AAWP has an article about [taking x20 Lumias to Redstone](http://allaboutwindowsphone.com/features/item/21625_To_Boldly_Go_taking_the_x20_Lu.php)
- someone at XDA Developers has made [an app that automates the hack to allow the upgrade](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/windows-10-mobile-apps-and-games/app-dht-upgrade-advisor-redstone-lumias-t3434774) (from a quick glance, the process appears more or less similar)
- there's also a separate guide at XDA Developers for [upgrading older Lumias from Windows Phone 8.1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-10-mobile/installing-windows-10-mobile-tech-t3431454) (presumably this is the one you'll want to follow first)

XDA Developers also has a ton of other interesting resources, including custom Windows 10 Mobile ROMs for several older Lumias. Well worth checking out if you have the time. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**No, it is not possible.**

As the upgrade advisor says, your phone is not elligible for Windows 10 upgrade. Also your phone model is not supported in the insider preview.

**Reference**

1. [Supported phones for Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview](https://insider.windows.com/Home/GetStarted/preview-supported-phones)